# org.postgresql.Driver not found after install application

Tags: java, postgresql

When I try to open a connection to a PostgreSQL database, I add this to recognize the driver:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

When I run the application for Netbeans/Eclipse, it works fine.
I'm generating a installer using InnoSetup to this application. After the installation, the postgresql.jar is already added to the folders, but I'm getting an error:

```
org.postgresql.Driver
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    fourcis.scb.utils.DatabaseUtilities.createDatabaseIfNotExists(DatabaseUtilities.java:19)
    fourcis.scb.threads.ThreadOperacoesDatabase.run(ThreadOperacoesDatabase.java:17)
```

This is occuring ONLY WHEN I'm installing the application. When I run from the IDE, it's working properly. Do you guys know what it could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the error stack, it looks like a classpath error. Is is trying to look for driver at runtime and not able to find it. You can try one of the following things to see if it fixes the issue

1) Set Classpath variable to include folder containing postgresql.jar

2) If feasible, run java commpand with classpath information.
[Way to set classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jar files under `/lib` folder. where your executable file is located.